# BizTalk FTP receive adapter - 550 error on NLST

Tags: ftp, biztalk

I'm trying to set up a BizTalk FTP receive location.  I have my FTP server set up with a /test subfolder that contains a CSV file.  I have tested the CSV file locally through the same receive port and it works fine.  The FTP port seems to be dying when doing an NLST command to list the contents of the /test folder based on the file mask that I set.  According to the logs, it is receiving a 550 response from the server.

Here is the log output:

```
< 220 Microsoft FTP Service
> USER XXXXXXXX
< 331 Password required for XXXXXXXX.
> PASS xxxx
< 230 User logged in.
> PWD
< 257 "/" is current directory.
> PWD
< 257 "/" is current directory.
> PWD
< 257 "/" is current directory.
> SYST
< 215 Windows_NT
> PWD
< 257 "/" is current directory.
> CWD /test/
< 250 CWD command successful.
> PWD
< 257 "/test" is current directory.
> TYPE A
< 200 Type set to A.
> PORT XXXXXXXX
< 200 PORT command successful.
> NLST *XXXXXXXX*.csv
< 150 Opening ASCII mode data connection.
< 550 
> QUIT
< 221 Goodbye.
```

When I use the Windows ftp command I can issue these same commands and it seems to work just fine.  FileZilla can connect to the FTP server without issue.  So I think this is an issue in the BizTalk client and not in the server.

I get the same results whether I set "Use name list (NLST)" to Yes or No in the port configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.  I had the FTP receive port configured to use Active mode and apparently a firewall somewhere between BizTalk and the server was blocking the port.  Switching to Passive mode in the receive port configuration caused things to start working.